# Foundation 6 sticky responsive menu on left

Tags: menu, zurb-foundation, sticky, screen-size

I start working with Foundation.
I would like to have a sticky responsive menu on the left side always visible except for small screen-size
It's about the same as this:

```
<https://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/BbyRav>
```

but I would like the menu to be a dropdown for small screen-size.

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a bit like this page:
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58931212/foundation-6-sticky-responsive-menu-on-left>
The menu on the left is "sticky" in desktop mode and becomes a dropdown menu for small screens

Comment: OK. I think I found it… I can use “Off-canvas” with .reveal-for-medium class: <https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#reveal-on-larger-screens>